# use where to find decimal element index failed

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, where-clause

I try to use `where` to find integer element index and it works.

But if I use `where` to find decimal element index and it return a empty tuple.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[6,7]])
b=np.arange(1,10,1)
c=np.where(b==a[1,1])
c
(array([4]),)
c[0][0]
4
a=np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[6,7]])
s=a*0.001
b=b*0.001
c=np.where(b==a[1,1])
c
(array([], dtype=int32),)
```

This is a fake question. The failure is because the target array was built with numpy.linspace method and that will produce some elements with many decimal digits. I input a limited digit data to find it in such array and np.where(array==data) can't find exactly matched items. The solution is to use np.round method to trim the array to limited digital number the same as that of  data.

Comment: Please exlain what result do you expect, and remove the uselsess lines in your snippet

Comment: I want to get an tuple that indicate the element index

Comment: How about `np.where(b==s[1,1])` - you might consider using `np.where(np.isclose(b,s[1,1]))` for checking floats.

Comment: Thanks WWII,  it works.